# Opening a url in my webview app from a notification not working when the app is coming from closed

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swift4.2

I have a webview ios app that receives notifications and I pass a url so that when the user clicks on the notification it will open the webview to that url.

When the app is in the foreground and background it works fine. If the user gets the notification when the app is closed and not currently running then the app opens but does not go to that url

In my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I detect the different states of the app but I thought that .background would work the same as not running but I guess it doesn't. How can I get the notification to open the url coming from when the app is closed?

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let data = userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .background {
        // background
        //print("==== Active Running ====")
        if let aps = data["aps"] {
            let url = aps["url"]
            viewController?.loadRequestnotification(for: url as! String)
        }
    }
    else if state == .inactive {
        // inactive
        //print("==== Inactive Running ====")
        if let aps = data["aps"] {
            let url = aps["url"]
            viewController?.loadRequestnotification(for: url as! String)
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

So with some help I have been able to use `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to call my webview, but the notification when pressed is still not opening to the url.

I use `viewController?.loadRequestnotification(for: url as! String)` in some other areas of my delegate that works fine. I am suspecting the `return true` might be conflicting the call.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.observeReachability()
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    registerForPushNotifications()

    if launchOptions != nil {
        // opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        let userInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
        if userInfo != nil {
            if let object = userInfo?["aps"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                let url = object["url"]
                viewController?.loadRequestnotification(for: url as! String)
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: AppDelegate.php ??? you are developing iOS app in PHP!!!

Comment: App was killed state, when notification is coming then your app in initialize and it's start from application lunch state, so that controller is not initialize before. it will never redirect to webview controller. first you need to identify your rootviewcontroller and then redirect to webviewcontroller. then it's work

Comment: At this point of time check didFinishLaunchingWithOptions -> launchOptions, there should be some dictionary with information.Try debugging this more deep.When that dictionary contains that url, redirect to respective viewcontroller.

Comment: Have you checked that `viewController` isn't `nil`? You could make a check and if it is, store the url in a variable and pass it on `viewController.didSet`

Comment: when the app is closed state you receive notification in `application(_: didLaunch option:_)`

Comment: @spatel lol sorry meant to write Swift

Comment: I have gotten a little farther. I have edited my question with an update if you guys can take a look.

Comment: When it is not working, try printing viewController object since it is optional object and see if it is nil or not.If it is nil then allocate it and then push to this viewController. If then nothing works then please explain in detail what is exactly happening.

Answer (score 1):

- didReceiveRemoteNotification won't be called while app is closed.

  Try this code when your app is closed to get notification data.

  ```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
       if launchOptions != nil {
         // opened from a push notification when the app is closed
          let userInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
         if userInfo != nil {
         if let object = userInfo?["aps"] {
             let url = object["url"]")
            // Now set root controller here
         }
       }
    } else {
       // opened app without a push notification.
           }
    }
  ```

Comment: take a look at my question. I have edited it. Got farther with your answer but the webview is still not opening the url. It just opens the app

Comment: are you getting url for webview in notification? and you have to set root controller (viewController -that contains webview) to open it.

Comment: I am assuming that `launchOptions` will contain the data from the notification when it was pressed?

Comment: you are doing something wrong with viewController?.loadRequestnotification(for: url as! String)

Comment: you cant start viewcontroller like this,instead you have to set it as root controller search it.

Comment: No, I use that also in my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` for when a notification is pressed when the app is in the background or foreground and it works fine.

Comment: I have edited answer. You have to set root controller there.check in google how to set root controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186157/discussion-between-cesar-bielich-and-punit).

Answer (score 0):

**There is one scenario** like your app is not running and user click on your app's notification then following the way you can get it.

Here is code you can get it

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    if let notification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any] {
        if let dictionary:NSDictionary = notification as? NSDictionary{
            print("Dictionary Print in didFinishLaunching :: \(dictionary)")
        }
    }

}
```

**Your app can received some notification and it is in notification center but user can not click on any notification but they will open your app as normally then following is a way, you can get all notification which is received by your app.**

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { (notification) in
        print(notification.count)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that called when app receives any notification.
I have used this in my chatting app.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if application.applicationState == .active {
        //Application is currently active and user receive the notification
    } else if application.applicationState == .background {
        //app is in background, but not killed
    } else if application.applicationState == .inactive {
        //app is transitioning from background to foreground (user taps notification), do what you need when user taps here
        //Load your URL into webView from here
    }
}
```

If app is open and you want to perform some action when notification is received 
Use this method

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptions.alert.rawValue | UIUserNotificationType.sound.rawValue | UIUserNotificationType.badge.rawValue)
}
```

You can also check weather the app is open from notification or not in 
`AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

But it is recommended to keep the this `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method light as possible.
I hope this will work for you